# Install pcntl extention on cent os 6.5 php 5.4.28

Tags: php

I have dedicated server on bluehost having CentOS 6.5 and PHP 5.4.28

I have an issue with regards to starting a service on specific port no. I log in from PuTTY as the root user, go to `home/fleeton/public_html/socket`, and give the following command:

```
php -q server.php
```

server.php has script to start service on port no 10000

After executing the above command, it shows me:

> This example requires PCNTL extention

Can you help me what steps I need to follow to install it?

Answer (score 0):

For php 5.4.x and centos 6.5 64, try this.

First you will need php-devel and gcc if don't have yet

```
yum install php54w-devel
```

If you don't have gcc

```
yum install gcc.x86_64
```

download php source code for your php version, you have installed on your server, for example php-5.4.xx.tar.gz from http://www.php.net/releases/

```
cd php-5.4.xx/ext/pcntl
phpize
./configure
make
```

copy the extension to modules folder, first find the location

```
php-config --extension-dir
cp modules/pcntl.so /usr/lib
```